Unable to connect to snowflake from DBT
I have been trying to connect to snowflake with dbt but I seem to be getting this error
00:46:36  1 check failed:
00:46:36  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

>Database Error
250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting

Check your database credentials and try again. For more information, visit:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile

My snowflake credential are ok,
the profile seem to be ok
the snowflake url : https://ab12345.eu-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com
profile.yml
master_sf_proj:
  outputs:
    dev:
    account: ab12345.eu-west-2.aws
    database: DEV
    password: *********
    role: ACCOUNTADMIN
    schema: PUBLIC
    threads: 1
    type: snowflake
    user: johndoe
    warehouse: COMPUTE_WH
  target: dev

not sure what I've done wrong here

It looks like the old URL format for Snowflake, is this what you get when you follow this: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier? Also, I hope the account, database etc. in your profile.yml are indented after dev
